# creating a cube in 3d

Tags: opengl

I am trying to add walls to my checkboard floor so that they form a cube, I have the bottom already but I am having difficulties to draw the back side or the walls.

Here is my code:

```
class Checkerboard {
  int displayListId;
  int width;
  int depth;
public:
  Checkerboard(int width, int depth): width(width), depth(depth) {}
  double centerx() {return width / 2;}
  double centerz() {return depth / 2;}
  void create() {
    displayListId = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(displayListId, GL_COMPILE);
    GLfloat lightPosition[] = {4, 3, 7, 1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3d(0, 1, 0);
    for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++) {
      for (int z = 0; z < depth - 1; z++) {
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE,
                     (x + z) % 2 == 0 ? RED : WHITE);
        glVertex3d(x, 0, z);
        glVertex3d(x+1, 0, z);
        glVertex3d(x+1, 0, z+1);
        glVertex3d(x, 0, z+1);
      }
    }
    glEnd();
    glEndList();
  }
  void draw() {
    glCallList(displayListId);
  }
}
```

;

I am trying to add the following code:

```
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);    // Color Yellow
    glVertex3d( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
    glVertex3d(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)
    glVertex3d(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
    glVertex3d( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
```

Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are effectively drawing the face you're trying to add, but you can't see it because of backface culling. Try `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` before drawing you quads, or try to change the order of the vertices.

Note: if you disable backface culling, consider it as a temporary workaround to debug your program. Backface culling is an important optimisation and it should be enabled in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);    // Color Yellow
glVertex3d( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3d( -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3d( -1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3d( 1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
```

Note your comments were in the right winding order (CCW) but your vertices were not (They were clock wise). OpenGL by default will cull them (not show them) because it thinks they are back faces if culling is enabled.

Comment: You say `OpenGL by default will cull them ...` which is not correct.  Face culling only occurs if you enable it `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`.

Comment: Sorry I meant by default OpenGL will cull back faces is culling is turned on.

Comment: No worries; I didn't down-vote it or anything.  Just wanting to make we're not propagating misinformation.

Comment: Added an edit to make it clear. Thanks again for the catch :)